# Find how many numbers that are perfect squares and the sqrt() is a prime number in a L, R range

Tags: c++, time-complexity, primes

First off all, feel free to improve the formatting of the question

> This question is already solved by Goswin von Brederlow!

Hello, i'm praticing programming and this problem came across and i don't know how is the best way to solve this:

> The question have T test cases that consists in:
>
> > Given a range L and R, find how many numbers meet the constraints:
> >
> > > i) Number is a perfect square;
> > >
> > > ii) The sqrt(Number) is a prime number.
>
> Limits:
>
> 1 <= T <= 1e4
>
> 1 <= L, R <= 1e12
>
> Time limit: 1 second

So, i tried it with a simple idea of pre-processing with an unodered_map(lld, bool) all the answers with the sieve of eratosthenes for each sqrt(Number) given that Number is a perfect square

After, I pass in range pow(sqrt(l), 2) and increments it the next odd number... like: 4 9 16 25, the difference are odd numbers: 5 7 9...

My code:

```
long long int l, r; scanf("%lld %lld", &l, &r);
long long int odd = ceil(sqrt(l)), n = odd*odd;
odd = (2*odd) + 1;
long long int ans = 0;
while((n >= l && n <= r)){
    it = h.find(n);
    ans = ans + it->second;
    n = n + odd; 
    odd = odd + 2;
}
```

But a i still got TLE, i need some help guys, thank you!

Comment: *i need some help* you need to follow the instructions here [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only question I see I infer from  "i don't know how is the best way to solve this".

Your way seems to be pretty smart already. You have some bugs even in just the bit of code you pasted. You seem to compute the sum of the numbers instead of counting them.

One thing I could think of improving is the counting itself. Looks like you have a hash table of all the squares of primes and you simply test all auqares if they are in the table.

Why not make a balanced tree out of the primes? In each node you store the minimum and maximum number and the count for the subtree. The leaves would be (n, n, 1) where n is one of the squares of primes. Given L and R you can then go through the tree and sum up all subtrees that are in the interval and recurse into subtrees that are only partially inside. Ignore everything outside. That should add a logarithmic factor to your complexity.

Comment: You don't even need a tree. You can make an array, do a binary or dictionary search for L and R and return their distance.